# Nested generic interfaces

Tags: c#, generics, interface

I have a schema of interfaces like the following (C# .NET4)

```
interface A 
{

}

interface B 
{
    List<A> a;
}

interface C 
{
    List<B> b;
}
```

and I implemented it in this way:

```
public interface A 
{

}

public interface B<T> where T : A 
{
    List<T> a { get; set; }
}

public interface C<T> where T : B
{
    List<T> b { get; set; } // << ERROR: Using the generic type 'B<T>' requires 1 type arguments
}
```

I don't know how to avoid the error **Using the generic type 'B' requires 1 type arguments**

Comment: You are not implementing any interfaces...

Comment: I used the wrong verb :) .. basically all the asnwers are good, thank you all

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since `interface B<T>` is generic, you need to provide a formal type argument for it when declaring `interface C<T>`. In other words, the current problem is that you are not telling the compiler what type of interface B interface C "inherits" from.

The two `T`s will not necessarily refer to the same type. They can be the same type, as in

```
public interface C<T> where T : B<T>, A { ... }
```

or they can be two distinct types:

```
public interface C<T, U> where T : B<U> where U : A { ... }
```

The restrictions on the type argument are of course tighter in the first case.

Answer (score 1):

C looks like Generic Generic type (for lack of a better word).

Would this definition of C work instead?

```
public interface C<T,U> where T : B<U> where U : A
{
    List<T> b{ get; set; } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

since generic type in interface `B` can only be an instance of type `A`, in interface `C` you need to declare `T` of type `B<A>`:

```
public interface A { }
public interface B<T> where T : A
{
    List<T> a { get; set; }
}
public interface C<T> where T : B<A>
{
    List<T> b { get; set; } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because you have a `<List<T>>` where `T` is `B<T>` at the moment you have it as a `List<B>` where you need to specify a type for `B`. This is the reason for your error.

```
public interface C<T, T2> where T : B<T2>
  where T2 : A
{
  List<T> b { get; set; } 
}
```

Cast `T2` to `A` and then you will be fine :)

Answer (score 1):

you can add one more interface here like

```
public interface A { }
public interface B<T> where T : A
{
    List<T> a { get; set; }
}
public interface BA : B<A>
{ 
}
public interface C<T> where T : BA
{
    List<T> b { get; set; } // << ERROR: Using the generic type 'B<T>' requires 1 type arguments
}
```

does it solve the purpose?