# Infer or ignore nested generics in nested C# interfaces

Tags: c#, generics

Let's say we have a container `IDevice` that contains `IDeviceTagBag` objects, and `IDeviceTagBag` itself is a container of `IDeviceTag` objects.

Now I want them to be generic classes, while maintaining the constraints above.

In **Java**, I would do the following:

```java
public interface IDeviceTag {}

public interface IDeviceTagBag<TDeviceTag extends IDeviceTag> {}

public interface IDevice<TDeviceTagBag extends IDeviceTagBag<?>> {}
```

Writing a method returning a `IDevice` (**Java** solution) now looks like this:

```java
public class DeviceService
{
    // Compiler will infer the following covariant chain:
    // -> ? extends IDeviceTagBag -> ? extends IDeviceTag
    public IDevice<?> Get(string name)
    {
        return null;
    }

    // Or the invariant alternative:
    // -> IDeviceTagBag -> IDeviceTag
    public IDevice<IDeviceTagBag<IDeviceTag>> GetInvariant(string name)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

I tried to achieve the same thing using **C#** (either invariant or covariant), but I ended up with the below solution that feels like a big boilerplate:

```cs
// OK !
public interface IDeviceTag {}

// OK !
public interface IDeviceTagBag<TDeviceTag> where TDeviceTag : IDeviceTag {}

// Ouch, no substitute for wildcard "<?>"
public interface IDevice<TDeviceTagBag, TDeviceTag>
    where TDeviceTagBag : IDeviceTagBag<TDeviceTag>
    where TDeviceTag    : IDeviceTag
{}
```

Writing a method returning a `IDevice` (**C#** solution) looks like this:

```cs
public class DeviceService
{
    // So much to replace "<?>"
    public IDevice<IDeviceTagBag<IDeviceTag>, IDeviceTag> Get(string name)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

I actually have a fourth nested generic interface in my application and it gets nasty.

Am I missing something that would simplify that, like in the **Java** solution with `<?>`?

After finding those posts...

- [Is there an anonymous generic tag in C# like in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/116830/is-there-an-anonymous-generic-tag-in-c-like-in-java)
- [Nested generic interfaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14497854/nested-generic-interfaces)

... I fear there is not much I can do about it.

Or am I over-engineering the thing? After all, if I remove the `where` constraints, I no longer have this boilerplate issue; but developers may implement `IDevice` of something else than `IDeviceTagBag`...

---

**Conclusion from answers (19.10.2019)**

- If your interfaces are read-only, you can make your interfaces covariant. See @Alpha75 answer.
- If your interfaces are **not** read-only, you can create non-generic interfaces that are "siblings" to your generic ones as a substitute to the Java `<?>` wildcard generic. See @canton7 answer.

Both answers are good, but I can only accept one... so I accept the one that replicates the most my Java solution. :(

---

**Appendix: why I need my interfaces to be generic**

I build a library that offers communication capabilities with various device types. A common action for all of them is to receive and send messages. Then, depending on the device type, there is additional capabilities.

Developers using the library may use the common `DeviceService` to access every devices, whatever the type, but will be limited to the common actions.

If they want to use a specific capability, they may use say `SpecificDeviceService`, but they will have to update their code if the underlying device type changes.

A `SpecificDevice` needs to implements `IDevice` if I want it to be accessible through either `DeviceService` or `SpecificDeviceService`:

```cs
public interface IDevice
{
    IDeviceTagBag Tags
    {
        get;
    }

    // ...
}

public interface ISpecificDevice : IDevice
{
    // Problem:
    // - "Tags" still return "IDeviceTagBag" here and not "ISpecificDeviceTagBag"
    // - End users will have to do explicit casts
}
```

To prevent the "problem" said in the comments, a solution is to use generics.

```cs
// New problem: "TDeviceTagBag" may be something else than "IDeviceTagBag"
public interface IDevice<TDeviceTagBag>
{
    TDeviceTagBag Tags
    {
        get;
    }

    // ...
}

public interface ISpecificDevice : IDevice<ISpecificDeviceTagBag>
{
    // First problem solved: "Tags" return "ISpecificDeviceTagBag"
}
```

But then, when constraining the generic types with `where` conditions to resolve the new problem above, I get the "boilerplate" code explained in my question above because I have a total of 4 layers:

```
IDeviceService -> IDevice -> IDeviceTagBag -> IDeviceTag
```

Comment: Without interface members it's hard to answer at your question. 
Generic type parameters are used in methods and property declarations inside interfaces and classes, so the answer depends on wich members are defined in the interface itself. Without using generics you can simply force developers to use IDevice using it in methods parameters or return types.

Comment: @RobertoFerraris thank you for your comment. I added an appendix explaining why I need generic interfaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If my understanding of your problem is correct, the C# way would be:

```
public interface IDeviceTag {}

public interface IDeviceTagBag {}
public interface IDeviceTagBag<TDeviceTag> : IDeviceTagBag where TDeviceTag : IDeviceTag {}

public interface IDevice<TDeviceTagBag> where TDeviceTagBag : IDeviceTagBag {}
```

That is, you have to manually split out the parts of `IDeviceTagBag` which depend on `TDeviceTag`, and those that don't. Then you expose the parts that don't depend on `TDeviceTag` on the non-generic interface `IDeviceTagBag`.

Your Java solution had:

```
public interface IDevice<TDeviceTagBag extends IDeviceTagBag<?>> {}
```

In my (somewhat rusty) understanding of Java wildcards, this means that you won't be able to treat any `TDeviceTag` members as anything other than `object`, which is roughly equivalent to only being able to access the members of the non-generic `IDeviceTagBag`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But in Java, `IDeviceTagBag<?>` means a `IDeviceTagBag` "of something". The compiler will check the "something" by looking at the `IDeviceTagBag` declaration, and it will found and infer `IDeviceTag` or to be more precise, `? extends IDeviceTag`. So no, it is not the same than using raw types. Your solution is nice but you will have the "explicit cast needed" problem explained in the appendix of my question.

Comment: The joys of there being multiple ways to solve the same problem!

Answer (score 2):

As I see it, you don't need two generic types for the third interface. You can solve it with a single where:

```
public interface IDeviceTag { }

public interface IDeviceTagBag<out TDeviceTag>
    where TDeviceTag : IDeviceTag
{ }

public interface IDevice<TDeviceTagBag>
    where TDeviceTagBag : IDeviceTagBag<IDeviceTag>
{ }
```

Comment: The problem is that, if `IDeviceTagBag` is not marked as covariant, someone won't be able to do `class DeviceTag : IDeviceTag { } class DeviceTagBag : IDeviceTagBag<DeviceTag> { } class Device : IDevice<DeviceTagBag> { }` [SharpLab](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgxg9gTgpgtADwGwBYA+ABATARgLABQGAzAAQCWAdgC4xQBmAhmDKQJIAiMAbuSwCqMA5qQDepAL6FCJCjTpMW7LrwHCAQsIA8/FXxiChAPkKkzpAO4ALOq1099h0iGUO1QwuKkEZZKrQZmVk43GB09d01jU3NrW1J7VQMNYWdXJMMorRCM4RMCL2kiMmxSCOSRFxzHVMKfYtJS8szUquaUoS124zFJItkm0LTqli7Qlp6vIA=)

Comment: Thanks, that is correct. I will mark it as covariant.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I made my interfaces covariant and it looks good since forcing covariance on my users is not an issue for me. But a bivariant solution seems impossible; did I found a "flaw" in the declaration-site variance model? :p

Comment: @kagmole just a FYI, bivariant would be something that had `<in out TDeviceTag>` behavior (which is indeed impossible). The term for just `<TDeviceTag>` is known as "invariant"

Comment: @ScottChamberlain you are right, I will update my question/comments to fix that.